# Magento - Add Logo to Printing

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

When people print any page on my store I would like to include our company logo on the page.. Any way of accomplishing this? I am working with Magento 1.5.1 .
When I say "print" I mean CONTROL-P or File-Print.. If this is not possible, what are my options?

Comment: when you simply click control-p, doesn't it print the entire page, with ads included?

Answer (score 1):

If your not referring to Magento's print option itself, you'll want to take a closer look at `@media="print"` CSS in order to control how a printed page (from the browsers print option) can be controlled.

http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/a/aa042103a.htm

I believe Magento has some print CSS you may want to take a look at to change out your logo.

/skin/frontend/default/default/images/logo_print.gif is the image your most likely looking to replace however.